# In which case we need to use HttpClient & other web services

Tags: java, http, rest

I had two questions:

1. In which case we need to use `HttpClient` and in which case we need to use other webservices like SOAP or JERSEY
2. What is the exact difference between `HttpClient` & other Webservices.

Comment: That's like asking "when do I need a food processor in stead of a knife". You could use both, but one of them is inevitably going to save you time.

Answer (score 1):

Webservices are Remote Procedure Calls exposed in a standard way, be it SOAP or REST protocols.  We use SOAP or REST clients in order to call that procedures, which use HTTP as its transport layer.

Apache HttpClient would be an option if you must retrieve information available by HTTP but not in a structured or RPC-ish manner.

FOR EXAMPLE:

- We would use a standard Webservice client in order to query Google Maps API
- We would use HttpClient in order to implement a web page crawler

Comment: Can you give one simple example for RPC with webservices ?

Comment: Apache HttpClient also a webservice ?

Comment: HttpClient is a library to retrieve information by HTTP protocol; it is in a lower level than webservices

Comment: You told HttpClient is lower level than webservices. Then any API Client in java equal to webservices ?

Comment: For example, CXF as I mentioned is a webservice-level library and toolset that can generate a webservice client for you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, almost every web service use HttpClient that's why we call it **"web"** service. It doesn't mean you can not use other communication protocol like sftp, ftp etc, you can.

SOAP (message infrastructure) which we exchange throuh http in normal SOAP based webservices.
Jersey provide api for java to implement restful webservices.

(Very ambiguous question. It's like comparing oranges and apple. :D)

HttpClient is nothing but a way to access resource using http protocol. Your web browser is also a httpClient which fetch webpages from server.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with an HTTP client you can do what a browser does. You can send an HTTP GET request to Web server and get a MIME file (html,image,xml etc.) with a specific URL.
You can prepare an HTTP packet, edit its headers and put request parameters in it programmatically.

It is theoritcally true to call a SOAP or REST style  Web Service with an simple HTTP client but practically not.